# Group action on the set of irreducible characters are orthogonal.

Tags: representation-theory, group-actions, orthogonality

I am studying representation theory and I came across the following problem:

Let $\mathbb{C}[G]$ be the set of $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions on a finite group $G$ and $S(\subset \mathbb{C}[G])$ be the set of irreducible characters of $G$. Let $\mathbb{C}_{\chi}[G]$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ generated by the set $\{g* \chi \; : \; g \in G \} $ where $g*\chi$ is the action of $G$ on $\chi$ defined as $(g*\chi)(x) = \chi (g^{-1}x) \; \forall x \in G$.

Let us define the scalar product $<|>: \mathbb{C}[G] \times \mathbb{C}[G] \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ s.t. $<\phi|\varphi> = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \phi(g) \overline{\varphi(g)}$.

Questions:

1. How do we show that if $\chi_1 \neq \chi_2$, then $\mathbb{C}_{\chi_1}[G]$ and $\mathbb{C}_{\chi_2}[G]$ are othogonal w.r.t. above scalar product?
2. Show that the subspaces $\mathbb{C}_{\chi}[G]$ are $\mathbb{C}[G \times G]$-submodules of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ irreducible by two non-isomporphs. (the action of $G \times G$ on $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is defined as $((g,h)*f)(x) = f (g^{-1}xh) $).

My attempt:

1. We have the following:
   \begin{align*}\label{key}
   \mathbb{C}_{\chi_1}[G] &= \text{span} \{ g*  \chi_1 \; : \; g \in G \} \\[2pt]
   \mathbb{C}_{\chi_2}[G] &= \text{span} \{ g*  \chi_2 \; : \; g \in G \}
   \end{align*}

The dot product $ \langle \phi,\varphi \rangle $can be written as
\begin{align*}
\langle \phi,\varphi \rangle &= \langle \sum_{g \in G} \lambda_g \left( g* \pi \right) , \sum_{h \in G} \lambda_{h}^{'} \left( h* \pi'  \right)  \rangle \\[2pt]
\text{After simplifying, we get} \\
& =  \sum_{g \in G} \sum_{h \in G} \lambda_g \overline{\lambda_{h}^{'}} \langle  \left( g* \pi \right) , \left( h* \pi'  \right)  \rangle 
\end{align*}

If $g=h$, then the product will be $0$ but what if $g \neq h$?

(2) I don't even understand the statement.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to use the notation $\mathbb{C}^G$ rather than $\mathbb{C}[G]$.

**(1)** It suffices to check the basis elements $g\ast\chi$ of $\mathbb{C}^G_\chi$ are orthogonal to the basis elements $h\ast\psi$ of $\mathbb{C}_\psi^G$:

$$ \langle g\ast\chi,h\ast\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{x\in G} \chi(g^{-1}x)\overline{\psi(h^{-1}x)}. \tag{$\circ$}$$

Suppose $\chi$ and $\psi$ are characters of $V$ and $W$. Note $\chi(g^{-1}x)\overline{\psi(h^{-1}x)}$ is then the trace of the linear map $T\mapsto (g^{-1}x)T(h^{-1}x)^{-1}$ on $V\otimes W^\ast \cong\hom(W,V)$. Then $(\circ)$ is the trace of

$$ T\mapsto g^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{x\in G} xTx^{-1}\right)h, $$

on $\hom(W,V)$ but by Schur's lemma the expression in parentheses is zero (it is the projection of $T$ onto $\hom_G(W,V)$), so this is the trace of the zero map, which is zero.

**(2)** Saying subspaces are irreducible "by two non-isomporphs" does not seem like gramamatical English, so perhaps there is a typo or you transcribed/translated incorrectly.

But we can show $\mathbb{C}_\chi^G$ is an irrep of $G\times G$. The key, at least in the following, is in understanding how the Artin-Wedderburn theorem says the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ acts on irreps $V$. Recall a rep is an algebra homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[G]\to\mathrm{End}(V)$, and AW says $\mathbb{C}[G]\to\bigoplus\mathrm{End}(V)$ is an isomorphism. Keep in mind, also, that $\mathrm{End}(V)\cong V\otimes V^\ast$ as a $G\times G$-rep (where $(g,h)T:=gTh^{-1}$, which is an irrep since $V$ is. (Recall that if $V$ is a $G$-irrep and $W$ is an $H$-irrep then $V\otimes W$ is a $G\times H$-irrep.)

Suppose $\chi$ is the character of an irrep $\rho_V$. Then any $f\in\mathbb{C}^G_\chi$ is expressible as

$$ f_u(x)=\mathrm{tr}\rho(ux) $$

for some $u\in\mathbb{C}[G]$ (the group algebra). There is some redundancy in representing functions this way, though. Indeed the map $\mathbb{C}[G]\to\mathbb{C}^G_\chi$ given by $u\mapsto f_u$ annihilates every summand of $\mathbb{C}[G]$'s AW decomposition except $\mathrm{End}(V)$. Note also $(g,h)\ast f_u=f_{hug^{-1}}$, so in fact we have an onto $G$-morphism from $\mathrm{End}(V)$ to $\mathbb{C}^G_\chi$. (I am sure there is a better way to explain this, but this is how I think about the problem.)

Comment: I have no idea how to you stated that $\chi(g^{-1}x)\overline{\psi(h^{-1}x)}$ is the trace of the linear map $T\mapsto (g^{-1}x)T(h^{-1}x)^{-1}$ on the tensor product of $V$ and $W^{dual}$. Can you please give reference to this fact or drop some hint here. (To be honest, I don't know much about the tensor products, so it would be better if you can give me the reference to read this stuff).

Comment: Well, $\psi_W(h^{-1}x)$ is the trace of $h^{-1}x$ on $W$, which means its conjugate is the trace of $h^{-1}x$ on the dual $\overline{W}$, and $\chi_V(g^{-1}x)$ is the trace of $g^{-1}x$ on $V$, and in general a product of characters is a character of a tensor product. Any treatment of representation theory should state these facts about dual reps and tensor products of reps and their characters. And $V\otimes W^\ast\cong\hom(V,W)$ (as reps) should also be covered in most rep thry texts.